# Working with List<String> and Reactive extensions

Tags: c#, vb.net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have started researching Reactive extensions and I would like to know how to do the following (ill try and keep it simple):

1. Have a list of string (or any other type)
2. When an item is added to the said list, do something with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that with the existing `List<String>` class - it doesn't provide notifications, and there's nothing that Reactive Extensions can do about that.

You might want to look at [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :) much appreciated

Answer (score 6):

Get [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net), then you can use the ReactiveCollection class - then you can use the ItemsAdded Observable.

```
ReactiveCollection<int> someCollection;

someCollection.ItemsAdded
    .Where(x => x > 100)
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Whoa! A big item was added!"));
```

Comment: Didn't know about ReactiveUI. Thanks for the heads up :) +1

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `List<T>`, or really any collection that implements `IEnumerable` then Rx isn't the answer. But if you have a *sequence* of items, some of which don't exist yet, then by all means, Rx is a good solution.